# Tutorials on OAuth2.0 on Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, android-browser

I am working on an Android app in PhoneGap and have to use OAuth 2.0. Furthermore the OAuth has to be in the external/native Android browser and cannot use ChildBrowser.

I would love to stick to JavaScript, but am willing to learn other stuff as long as I have a pretty solid tutorial (PHP, Perl, Ruby, etc).

I found this site that does non-PIN OAuth 1.0a authentication, but unfortunately I really need an OAuth 2.0 tutorial. http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1

Basically if you have found any good examples or are willing to put up some examples, I would love to see them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use any provider, Facebook providers a tutorial with a working code example and JavaScript SDK (recommended by FB for use in mobile apps and websites). If you're looking for a native Android Solution, they also provide a tutorial with SDK and code samples for Android. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/